# Xamarin.Forms + MvvmCross + AppCenter

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross, visual-studio-app-center

I have Xamarin.Forms with MvvmCross (version 5.5) and I want to connect to AppCenter.

I tried to call AppCenter.Start on many places but when I called

```
bool enabled = await Distribute.IsEnabledAsync();
```

in app, it always return false. I tried in project without MvvmCross and it return true.

Thanks for help.

**EDIT**

So finally I upgraded to MvvmCross 6.0.1

in splashScreen I am calling AppCenter.Start and it worked.

```
    public class SplashScreen : MvxFormsSplashScreenActivity<Setup, MvxApp, FormsApp>
    {
        protected override void RunAppStart(Bundle bundle)
        {
            AppCenter.Start(
                "android=xxx;",
                typeof(Analytics),
                typeof(Crashes),
                typeof(Distribute));

            StartActivity(typeof(FormsApplicationActivity));
            base.RunAppStart(bundle);
        }
    }
```